# Activity loads data twice

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, android-lifecycle

There is one `Activity` - called `MainActivity`. There is one `xml` - called `activity_main`. It contains a menu layout and game layout.

Menu layout - contains a "Start Match" `Button`

Game layout - contains a `Listview` with 4 `String` items (4 words...) and a "Done" `Button`

When the app launches, the menu layout is visible and game layout hidden. When the "Start Game" `Button` is clicked, the menu layout is hidden and the game layout is shown. When the "Done" `Button` is clicked the menu layout is shown and the game layout is hidden.

**Problem**: When I start a new game after clicking the "Done" `Button`, the previous games data is loaded onto the current game:

The `Listview` has 8 items instead of 4.

I assume it has to do with the `onSaveInstanceState`: `onDestroy()` is never called so when I click on "Start Match" a second time, it loads the state of the previous game.

Also, `onResume()` gets called after clicking "Start Match" the second time, so `onCreate()` and `onStart()` never get called again - unless I exit the app and launch again.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. I tried making the `onSaveInstanceState` null but that did not help:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(newMatch)
        outState=null;
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState(): onSaveInstanceState called");
}
```

Can someone please help?

Please tell me if I need to provide more code or info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you write 2 classes instead of just one?

- One class would be for the menu, with just one layout
- The second one for the game itself

With these you ensure the values of the game are always loaded in the same way, without being affected by previous games.

Comment: Do you mean two activities - as in, one activity for the menu and one activity for the game?

Comment: Exactly, that would be easier and more intuitive

Comment: Ok, so here's the full situation:

I am following Google's multiplayer tutorial and for some reason they keep the menu logic and game logic in one activity. So I need to keep everything in one class unfortunately to be able to connect to the mGoogleApiClient. -- but yes you are very correct. It would be much easier to create two separate classes. But I cannot :(

Comment: So do you have any advice on how I can solve this issue using one Activity?

Comment: Mmm not really, sorry... hope someone else can help

Comment: I was able to fix it in the end with your advice. thanks